# Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement len when using DeepVOG

Tags: python, keras, typeerror

I am trying to use DeepVOG as a python module, but end up with the following issue every time. I can install and import deepvog, then the problem appears with `model = deepvog.load_DeepVOG()`:

```
c:\users\anwender\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py in __len__(self)
    220 
    221   def __len__(self):
--> 222     raise TypeError('Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not '
    223                     'implement `__len__`. You may be '
    224                     'trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs '

TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement `__len__`. You may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model. This error will also get raised if you try asserting a symbolic input/output directly.
```

I could not find a point where or reason why .len() is called to get to `__len__`. I also used virtual environments with different versions, which did not help with this problem.